# Is it possible to view detailed GSM information on my Android phone?

Tags: system-info

I'm trying to find such an app, but I can't, which leads me to suspect that it's not possible, either because of software or hardware limitations. What I'd like to see is a list of cell towers that my phone can reach (both from my carrier and other carriers); signal strengths from each; perhaps an option to lock on to a specific tower or forbid the use of some tower. And, generally, the more data available, the better. So - have I just missed the right app; is there no such thing out there (and I'm free to write the first one); or is such data simply unavailable and I can just give up?

Answer (score 3):

There is this app called [Antennas](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.technolatry.antennas). It can't do everything you have asked for. But it can show you the tower you are connected to, the signal level, and other towers from you carrier that your phone can see/connect to and their signal level.

> Map the GSM/CDMA antennas in your neighborhood. This app monitors the
>   GSM/CDMA cellular network connection; displays a map of approximate
>   cellular antenna locations and their RF signal strength; and can log
>   the data to a text or KML file.
>
> Does not work on Verizon 3G & CDMA Support is limited by Android, not by the application CDMA requires Eclair Works
>   best with 2G GSM. 3G/CDMA support is very limited.

Comment: Well, that's at least something. I really wanted to see data about other carriers too though, to see which one has the best signal in my remote location. I guess I can buy cheap pre-paid SIM cards from them... but that's a lot of hassle. :P

Answer (score 1):

[Open Signal Map](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal) does some very similar stuff, its accuracy depends on how much data its got for your current area, but seems pretty good in built up areas.

I used it to help work out why I always had such a terrible signal at my parents house, turned out my phone kept connecting to a cell tower on the island you can just see from the end of their road, rather than the cell tower two roads down.

Comment: But they just use statistically gathered data, not what my phone can actually sense, right?

Comment: @Vilx- Yes, but your phone contributes to the data. Even Google doing their coarse location detection via cell-tower triangulation only have statistical, crowd-sourced data (for most phone networks at least). I don't think the phone companies release the exact location details of all their phone masts to anyone.